# Name and theory of multi-valued functions $F:\mathbb{N}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^l$

Tags: reference-request, computability-theory, arithmetic-functions

In computability theory there are considered mostly single-valued functions $f:\mathbb{N}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. (Let $\mathbb{N}$ be a placeholder for $\mathbb{N}$ or any initial segment $[0,n]$ of $\mathbb{N}$.)

Multi-valued functions $F:\mathbb{N}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^l$ seem to be just vectors of single-valued functions:

$$F(n) = \langle F_1(n),\dots,F_k(n)\rangle$$

Correspondingly, there are not so many atomic proper **names** for multi-valued  functions, but - if at all - only "vectors" of names like $\langle$carry, sum$\rangle$ for the function $F:[0,3] \rightarrow [0,1]^2$ with $F(0)=\langle0,0\rangle$, $F(1)=\langle0,1\rangle$, $F(2)=\langle1,0\rangle$, $F(3)=\langle1,1\rangle$. Note, that $\langle$full-adder$\rangle$ would be an appropriate *atomic* proper name for this function.

Since the family of multi-valued functions $F:\mathbb{N}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^l$ would be too vast, I'd like to restrict them to those which fulfill the conditions (with $N = \sum_i^k n_i$):

$$F(\langle n_1,\dots,n_k\rangle) = F(N)$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{l} F_i(n) =N$$

$$\forall_{i \leq l} \ F_i(n) \not\equiv 0$$

The last condition forbids trivial (= constant) output channels. (Note that $F_i(0) = 0$.)

Note, that the function $F:[0,3] \rightarrow [0,1]^3$ with $F(0)=\langle0,0,0\rangle$, $F(1)=\langle0,1,0\rangle$, $F(2)=\langle1,0,1\rangle$, $F(3)=\langle1,1,1\rangle$ implying $F_1(n) \equiv F_3(n)$ for all $n$ fulfills these conditions.

Questions:

> Does this family of multi-valued  functions have a name, e.g.
>   "integrating conservative functions" (since the integrated input number $N$ is somehow conserved)?
>
> Is there a worked-out theory of "integrating conservative functions"?
>
> What would be some interesting, non-trivial facts about "integrating conservative functions"? (E.g. which subsets are "computationally complete"?)

Comment: In my experience, computability theorists are happy to code any finite structure with a natural number. They happily consider functions of the form $n\mapsto A_n$, where $A_n$ is any kind of finite structure, including the kinds of tuples you are considering. For this reason, your remark that they don't consider such functions "in their own right, but just as vectors of single-valued functions" doesn't ring true to me.

Comment: Agreeing on that, can't you figure out what I try to say? My tuples are not to be considered as *any* kind of finite structure but just as tuples of integers. So my approach is much more naive. (You can do computability theory just thinking of integers and tuples of integers and how to transform them one into another, not of the fact that integers can encode arbitrary structures, especially tuples of integers, can't you? Possibly, one can *not*!)

Comment: Would it be of help, if I just dropped the remark "not considered in their own right"?

Comment: Yes. My point was also that your question isn't really about multi-valued functions. Rather, you are mapping partitions of $N$ to other partitions of $N$.

Comment: How are tuples of integers (of a fixed length) to be considered as partitions?

Comment: I meant partition in the sense that you have a list of numbers adding to $N$, and then you map it to another list of numbers adding to $N$.

Comment: That's it, thanks! So my question is just about functions mapping $k$-partitions of numbers N (not the *set* $\mathbb{N}$) to $l$-partitions of N. Now I know the name of this family of functions! And now I'd like to know if there is a worked-out theory of these functions. Is there a monograph?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68654/discussion-between-hans-stricker-and-joel-david-hamkins).